# Promise.all doesn't set isError to true if one fetch is working

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have a fetch function using `useQuery` that looks something like:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const { isError, refetch, isFetching } = useQuery(
        ["my_fetch"],
        () =>
            Promise.all([
                fetchData("fetch_one", { data1 }),
                fetchData("fetch_two", { data2 }),
            ]),
        {
            retry: false,
            onSuccess: ([fetch1, fetch2]) => {
                const combinedData = { ...fetch1, ...fetch2 };
                setData(combinedData);
            },
        }
    );
```

My problem is that I use the `isError` state for various stuff. However, if one of the fetches works it goes onto to `onSuccess`, but then I miss some of the data. I would actually just like to have no success unless both are fetched. How do I do that?